# Copying table from Excel to Word bookmark using VBA code

Tags: excel, ms-word, bookmarks, vba

I actually need your help on modifying this macro code. I got this code from somewhere else (sorry, forgot his name!). Basically, I have table data source from Sheet1 of excel. I need to transfer this table, keeping the formatting like borders, font size, auto fit, etc to MS Word with my bookmark named 'bookmark'. 
Something to note:

1. Bookmark's location is at the VERY LAST PARAGRAPH. I have more than 12 paragraphs in my Word file but the table should be placed at the very last paragraph.
2. Please note the number of rows and columns in the table data source is dynamic. This means, the number of rows and columns are not fixed. It can change. My existing macro code works for this. However, it entirely deleted the existing paragraphs. The table replaced everything on my file. I dont know the exact macro code to place this table to where the bookmark is.

Appreciate your help on item 2. Below is the code:

---

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
On Error Resume Next

    ' FIRST GET THE ROWS COLUMNS OF A USED RANGE.

    Dim iTotalRows As Integer   ' GET TOTAL USED RANGE ROWS.
    iTotalRows = Worksheets("sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count


    Dim iTotalCols As Integer   ' GET TOTAL COLUMNS.
    iTotalCols = Worksheets("sheet1").UsedRange.Columns.Count



    ' WORD OBJECT.
    Dim oWord As Object
    Set oWord = CreateObject(Class:="Word.Application")
    oWord.Visible = True
    oWord.Activate

    ' ADD A DOCUMENT TO THE WORD OBJECT.
    Dim oDoc
    Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open("C:\Macro\samplebookmark1.docx")


    ' CREATE A RANGE FOR THE TABLE INSIDE WORD DOCUMENT.
    Dim oRange
    Set oRange = oDoc.Range


    ' CREATE AND  DEFINE TABLE STRUCTURE USING
        ' THE ROWS AND COLUMNS EXTRACTED FROM EXCEL USED RANGE.
    oDoc.Tables.Add oRange, iTotalRows, iTotalCols


    ' CREATE A TABLE OBJECT.
    Dim oTable
    Set oTable = oDoc.Tables(1)
    oTable.Borders.Enable = True      ' YES, WE WANT BORDERS.


    Dim iRows, iCols As Integer


    ' LOOP THROUGH EACH ROW AND COLUMN TO EXTRACT DATA IN EXCEL.
    For iRows = 1 To iTotalRows
        For iCols = 1 To iTotalCols
            Dim txt As Variant
            txt = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRows, iCols)
            oTable.cell(iRows, iCols).Range.Text = txt        ' COPY (OR WRITE) DATA TO THE TABLE.


            ' BOLD HEADERS.
            If Val(iRows) = 1 Then
                objTable.cell(iRows, iCols).Range.Font.Bold = True
            End If
        Next iCols
    Next iRows

    Set oWord = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is within this line:

```
Set oRange = oDoc.Range
```

As it is now, it defines whole document range instead of bookmark's range.
You should use something like:

```
Set oRange = oDoc.Bookmarks("BookmarkName").Range
```

---

Concerning your new problem, one way to fix it is to put table directly into document's last paragraph without using a bookmark.

```
Set oRange = oDoc.Range.Paragraphs(oDoc.Range.Paragraphs.Count).Range
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved my Friday! Have a great day!

Comment: Hi Sir! I figured this out myself! Thank you very much! I have few more questions. My VBA macro remains same. 1. I only want to copy paste table range NOT including cells embedded with formula that returns empty strings. With my current code, it does include. I suspected because of this "UsedRange" in both itotalrows and itotalcolumns. How can I edit this please? 2. Also, when I copy and paste the data with format, my figures in excel has comma but when it's exported to my word using mail merge, it doesn't have commas and .00 anymore.How can I modify my macro? Thank you much in advance, Sir!

Comment: @LadyTiara There is nothing in your code to do with a mailmerge.

Answer (score 0):

Since "the table should be placed at the very last paragraph", you don't need a bookmark or any convoluted range setting. All you need is:

```
With oDoc
  Set oTable = .Tables.Add .Range.Characters.Last, iTotalRows, iTotalCols
End with
```

As for the output formatting, , instead of:

```
txt = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRows, iCols)
            oTable.cell(iRows, iCols).Range.Text = txt
```

use:

```
oTable.cell(iRows, iCols).Range.Text = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRows, iCols).Text
```

At a more basic level, why don't you simply copy and paste the Excel range as a single step, rather than going through the convoluted table creation and cell-by-cell population?